# C# converted from VB doesn't work

Tags: c#

I used code converter to go from VB to C# and I get errors in c#. specifically, error on `Item` and on `string.join(",", Flop.ToArray)`. Error says it doesn't contain a definition for `item` but it works in VB.

VB

```
Dim Flop As New List(Of String)
    For x As Integer = 0 To Dataset9.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 'ROWS
        Flop.Add(Dataset9.Tables(0).Rows(x).Item("Id"))
    Next
    strAllRoleNames = String.Join(",", Flop.ToArray)
```

C#

```
List<string> Flop = new List<string>();

    for (int x = 0; x <= Dataset9.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; x++)
      {
         Flop.Add(Dataset9.Tables[0].Rows[x].Item["Id"]);
      }
 strAllRoleNames = string.Join(",", Flop.ToArray);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<string> Flop = new List<string>();

    for (int x = 0; x <= Dataset9.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; x++)
      {
         Flop.Add(Dataset9.Tables[0].Rows[x]["Id"].ToString());
      }
 strAllRoleNames = string.Join(",", Flop.ToArray());
```

They three keys that were missing here

1. Accessing the item in a row, you need to use the C# default indexer as Item doesn't exist in C#
2. Since the cell in a row is an object and you want a string, need to explicitly call ToString
3. When calling ToArray, you need the () at the end in C#

Comment: The idea here being that the Item property is the default indexer for this object in C#. Unlike VB, C# doesn't offer named indexers, only a default indexer.

Comment: the string join is fixed by this, but the flop.add line is fixed by answer from christiandev

Comment: Eric - Much better worded I updated my post a bit for better clarity

Answer (score 2):

try...

```
Flop.Add(Dataset9.Tables[0].Rows[x]["Id"].ToString());
```

Comment: still says system.data.datarow does not contain a definition for item

Comment: this one worked...for that line...the string join was fixed by above answer

Comment: @mlg74, I only quickly read the quesiton, my bad...I see you have two errors, missing parenthesis on the second issue.

Answer (score 2):

ToArray is a method()

```
List<string> Flop = new List<string>();

    for (int x = 0; x <= Dataset9.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; x++)
      {
        Flop.Add(Dataset9.Tables[0].Rows[x]["Id"]);
      }
 strAllRoleNames = string.Join(",", Flop.ToArray());
```

Comment: the string join is fixed by this, but the flop.add line is fixed by answer from christiandev

Answer (score 1):

In a more concise way you can try below instead:

```
strAllRoleNames = string.Join(",", Dataset9.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                                   .Select(C => Convert.ToString(C["Id"]))
                                   .ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below changes:

```
Dataset9.Tables[0].Rows[x].Item["Id"] => Dataset9.Tables[0].Rows[x]["Id"]

Flop.ToArray => Flop.ToArray()
```